# Splitting and Creating New Columns and Populating Them with the Split Values in Python

Tags: python, split

In a data frame, among other columns, I have columns called fee, apr, offer, term. The dtype is object. The data looks like this:
[image]

EXAMPLE DATA:

FEE:
1)#2.490000#2.490000#3.490000#2.990000#2.990000#3.990000
2)#2.490000#2.490000#3.490000#2.990000#2.990000#3.990000#4.990000#4.990000#4.990000
3)#3.990000#3.990000#3.990000#4.990000#4.990000#4.990000#4.990000#4.990000#4.990000

apr:

1. #15.490000#15.490000#15.490000#15.990000#15.990000#16.990000
2. #13.490000#13.490000#13.490000#13.990000#13.990000#15.490000#17.490000#17.490000#17.490000
3. #18.990000#18.990000#18.990000#20.990000#20.990000#20.490000#21.990000#21.990000#21.990000

term:

1. #24#24#24#36#36#36
2. #24#24#24#36#36#36#60#60#60
3. #36#36#36#48#48#48#60#60#60

offer:
1)#LOWER#PRIMARY#HIGHER#LOWER#PRIMARY#HIGHER
2)#LOWER#PRIMARY#HIGHER#LOWER#PRIMARY#HIGHER#LOWER#PRIMARY#HIGHER
3)#LOWER#PRIMARY#HIGHER#LOWER#PRIMARY#HIGHER#LOWER#PRIMARY#HIGHER

What I am trying to achieve is to transform the given data into a new format where the rows are expanded based on combinations of term, offer, fee, and apr. Additionally, I want to extract specific values from the fee and apr strings and organize them into new columns while still retaining the existing columns. If row has no data in the columns then new columns should be blank.

The expected result should look something like this:
[image]

( while not included in example, columns for be also 72 and 84 for LOWER, PRIMARY, HIGHER as well)

I have tried this in python. The columns are generating correctly but I get nothing but NaN populating where there should be values:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import re

    def extract_value(s, prefix, term):
        if isinstance(s, float) or isinstance(term, float):
            return np.nan

        values = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', s)
        term_values = re.findall(r'\d+', term)


        for value, t in zip(values, term_values):
           if pd.notnull(t) and prefix in t and term in t:
               return float(value)
        return np.nan


    # List of prefixes and terms
    prefixes = ['LOWER', 'PRIMARY', 'HIGHER']
    terms = ['24', '36', '48', '60', '72', '84']


    # Iterate through rows and populate new columns
    for index, row in my_df_scored_test.iterrows():
        for prefix in prefixes:
            for term in terms:
                new_apr_col = f'{prefix} {term} apr'
                new_fee_col = f'{prefix} {term} fee'
                my_df_scored_test.at[index, new_apr_col] = extract_value(row['apr'], prefix, 
                row['term'])
                my_df_scored_test.at[index, new_fee_col] = extract_value(row['fee'], prefix, 
                row['term'])
```

I have also tried this and get the same result, columns generating correctly, but still get NaN:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    # Function to extract values
    def extract_value(s, prefix):
        if isinstance(s, str):
            values = [float(v.split('#')[int(i)]) for v, i in zip(s.split('#'), 
                     range(len(s.split('#')))) if prefix in v]
            return values
        else:
            return []

    # Apply the function to create new columns for all prefixes and terms
    prefixes = ['LOWER', 'PRIMARY', 'HIGHER']
    terms = ['24', '36', '48', '60', '72', '84']

    for prefix in prefixes:
        for term in terms:
            term_filter = my_df_scored_test['term'].str.contains(f'#{term}#')
    
            new_apr_col = f'{prefix} {term} apr'
            new_fee_col = f'{prefix} {term} fee'
    
            apr_values = []
            fee_values = []
    
            for idx, row in my_df_scored_test.iterrows():
                if term_filter[idx]:
                    extracted_apr = extract_value(row['apr'], prefix)
                    extracted_fee = extract_value(row['fee'], prefix)
                    if len(extracted_apr) > 0:
                        apr_values.append(extracted_apr[0])
                    else:
                        apr_values.append(np.nan)
                    if len(extracted_fee) > 0:
                        fee_values.append(extracted_fee[0])
                    else:
                        fee_values.append(np.nan)
                else:
                    apr_values.append(np.nan)
                    fee_values.append(np.nan)
    
            my_df_scored_test[new_apr_col] = apr_values
            my_df_scored_test[new_fee_col] = fee_values
```

Here is an example of what I get when I run either pieces of the code:
[image]
[image]

Comment: One possible issue is that there's a check `if prefix in v` which I kind of think is checking '#' in row 1 (lower primary 36,...) not the row (#15.234.....). Please try once after removing that condition